# In PHP 8 how to check with reflection whether passing an object will work?

Tags: php

Let's say I have

```
class X {
}
class Y {
}
function foo(X|Y $param) {
}
class Z extends Y {
}
class U {
}
```

Now, how could one verify that passing an instance of Z to `foo` works but an instance of U will not? Manually, it'd look like...

```
$r = new \ReflectionFunction('foo');
$found = FALSE;
foreach ($r->getParameters()[0]->getType()->getTypes() as $type) {
  $name = $type->getName();
  if ($name && is_subclass_of('\Z', $name)) {
    $found = TRUE;
  }
}
```

This is ugly to say the least and I am not even sure whether the non-emptiness check of `$name` is necessary.

Is there perhaps some "type matches" functionality in PHP 8?

Comment: Do you need reflection for that? Doesn't the interpreter take care of it?

Comment: One, it's done already for a single type in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21Compiler%21TaggedHandlersPass.php/function/TaggedHandlersPass%3A%3AprocessServiceCollectorPass/8.4.x and it is semi-obvious it'll need to be extended. Two, I have PHP docs commit access and I'd like to document this if it exist, doh the entire shebang is undocoument as of yet.

Comment: The question does not clearly express your needs.

Comment: The function you're looking for doesn't exist _yet_, but there has been a suggestion on the mailing list that it could be added: https://externals.io/message/113016

Comment: Why do you need to do that check in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand *why* you want to check this yourself, when the interpreter already takes care of it, raising the correct error.

```
<?php

class X {
}

class Y {
}

function foo(X|Y $param) {
}

class Z extends Y {
}

class U {
}

$x = new X;
$y = new X;
$z = new Z;
$u = new U;

foo($x);
foo($y);
foo($z);
foo($u);
```

If you run this code, you will see that PHP correctly throws a `TypeError` on line 26, which is where `foo($u)` is being called, while all the other calls work:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: foo(): Argument #1 ($param) must be of type X|Y, U given, called in /in/Ffidj on line 26 and defined in /in/Ffidj:9
Stack trace:
#0 /in/Ffidj(26): foo(Object(U))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/Ffidj on line 9

Process exited with code 255.
```

If you need to, you could simply wrap the call to `foo` in a `try catch` block to intercept the `TypeError`:

```
<?php

class X {
}

class Y {
}

function foo(X|Y $param) {
}

class Z extends Y {
}

class U {
}

function safeFoo($param) {
    try {
        foo($param);
        echo 'OK' . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (TypeError $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$x = new X;
$y = new X;
$z = new Z;
$u = new U;

safeFoo($x);
safeFoo($y);
safeFoo($z);
safeFoo($u);
```

Output:

```
OK
OK
OK
foo(): Argument #1 ($param) must be of type X|Y, U given, called in /in/sEQIQ on line 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for php 8:

https://3v4l.org/6AnNZ#v8.0.17

UPD: Sorry for only-link answer, but there are a lot of code, and formatting it inside the stackoverflow editor is hard. So I put it in the most popular php sandbox 3v4l.org.

The code defines function for checking if variable is acceptable by given function.

UPD2: Here is the code

```
function isCompatibleWithType(string $type, mixed $value): bool {
    if (gettype($value) === 'object') {
        return get_class($value) === $type || is_subclass_of($value, $type);
    }
    
    return gettype($value) === $type;
}

function canAccept(callable $func, int $paramPosition, mixed $paramValue): bool {
    $r = new \ReflectionFunction($func);
    
    foreach ($r->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        if ($parameter->getPosition() !== $paramPosition) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $type = $parameter->getType();
        if ($type instanceof \ReflectionUnionType) {
            foreach ($type->getTypes() as $t) {
                if (isCompatibleWithType($t->getName(), $paramValue) || ($t->allowsNull() && is_null($paramValue))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
            return false;
        } 
        
        if ($type instanceof \ReflectionIntersectionType) {
            foreach ($type->getTypes() as $t) {
                if (!isCompatibleWithType($t->getName(), $paramValue)) /* intersection types do not support nullables for now */ {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        
        return isCompatibleWithType($type->getName(), $paramValue) || ($t->allowsNull() && is_null($paramValue));
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
$r = new \ReflectionFunction('foo');
$found = FALSE;
foreach ($r->getParameters() as $parameter) {
    if ($parameter->getClass()->isSubclassOf('Z')) {
        $found = TRUE;
    }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#102988

Comment: Not in PHP 8. https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/5209 `ReflectionParameters::getClass()` is deprecated and doesn't work for union types.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. Since **PHP8** is still **unreleased**, **unstable** and **undocumented** I didn't know where to check, also any answer would be temporary until release.

Comment: `getClass`, `isArray`, and `isCallable` on `ReflectionParamter` class are deprecated: https://php.watch/versions/8.0/deprecated-reflectionparameter-methods